# justify: space-between with right aligned last element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Is there a way to accomplish this (with flexbox, or other)?

[image: evenly distributed text]

- evenly distributed text
- but **first and last element sticks to the sides**

I'm assuming this would need the flex items to be shrinkwrapped, which (I think) isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`space-between` will work- check out the example below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper > * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Another way is using `auto` margins for the items at the end- but it has a different effect- see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.wrapper > * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! The secret is to NOT set a "flex: x x auto" on the child element. Then, the child elements will be shrinkwrapped to the minimum size. Fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox you could use the **justify-content** property to define the item's distribution behavior.

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

is what you need is what you need.

Here is a example:
http://codepen.io/fazermokeur/pen/WGJpJO

(directly inspired by this perfect resource about flexbox:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ )

Comment: thanks but the first and the last are not aligned to the sides. In this codepen (fork of yours) http://codepen.io/joe_g/pen/QKAvpB – I'd like one to be left aligned (stick to the left margin) and "six" be sticking to the right margin.